# Option Value as Link in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am implementing option value into a page and I want to use it as navigation menu with links to different pages. The code below does switch between pages but it immediately returns the pages to index.html As a result, you can see another page for a fraction of a second and then it comes back to the home page. Any thoughts on that, please?

My code is as followed:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start of index page -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="index">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>HOME</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-custom-1"></label>
    <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="index.html">HOME</option>
        <option value="#about">ABOUT</option>
        <option value="#services">SERVICES</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#select-custom-1').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <p>Home Page</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /index page -->

<!-- Start of about page -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="about">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>ABOUT</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-custom-1"></label>
    <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="index.html">HOME</option>
        <option value="#about">ABOUT</option>
        <option value="#services">SERVICES</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#select-custom-1').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <p>About Page</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /about page -->

    <!-- Start of services page -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="services">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>SERVICES</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-custom-1"></label>
    <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="index.html">HOME</option>
        <option value="#about">ABOUT</option>
        <option value="#services">SERVICES</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#select-custom-1').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <p>Services Page, Services Page</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /services page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start of index page -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="index">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>HOME</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-custom-1"></label>
    <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="index.html">HOME</option>
        <option value="#about">ABOUT</option>
        <option value="#services">SERVICES</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#select-custom-1').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              $.mobile.changePage( url, { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <p>Home Page</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /index page -->

<!-- Start of about page -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="about">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>ABOUT</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-custom-1"></label>
    <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="index.html">HOME</option>
        <option value="#about">ABOUT</option>
        <option value="#services">SERVICES</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#select-custom-1').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              $.mobile.changePage( url, { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <p>About Page</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /about page -->

    <!-- Start of services page -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="services">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>SERVICES</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-custom-1"></label>
    <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="index.html">HOME</option>
        <option value="#about">ABOUT</option>
        <option value="#services">SERVICES</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#select-custom-1').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              $.mobile.changePage( url, { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <p>Services Page, Services Page</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /services page -->

</body>
</html>
```

You need to use jQuery Mobile solution for page traversing:

```
$.mobile.changePage( url, { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gajotres. Your help is much appreciated! Thank You Thank You Thank You